# Are Gamma 1 and Gamma 2 stronger than Super Saiyan Blue?

Tags: dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-movies

There are statements by guidebooks and authors saying Gamma 1 and Gamma 2 are the strongest androids. This would mean they are stronger than 17 I guess? And since 17 had a sparring match with Super Saiyan Blue Goku, which looked pretty even, does this mean Gamma 1 and Gamma 2 are stronger than a Super Saiyan Blue?

I'm aware there are other events and statements by other characters which could confirm and deny this idea, how do all of them fit?